# How to change Navigation shadow color when changed mode?

Tags: ios, swift

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.shadowColor = ColorPalette.navigationBarShadowColor.cgColor
```

Set color according to traits mode.

```
class ColorPalette : NSObject {

    static var navigationBarShadowColor: UIColor {       
        return UIColor { (traits) -> UIColor in
            //dark: Black // light: grey16
            return traits.userInterfaceStyle == .dark ?
            UIColor.black : UIColor(hex: "dbdbdc")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a swift file add the below code in that file.

```
public enum Mode {
    
    public enum Colors {
        public static var backgroundColor: UIColor = {
            if #available(iOS 13, *) {
                return UIColor { (UITraitCollection: UITraitCollection) -> UIColor in
                    switch UITraitCollection.userInterfaceStyle {
                        case .light, .unspecified:
                            // light mode detected
                            return .blue
                        case .dark:
                            // dark mode detected'
                            return .yellow
                        @unknown default:
                            return .red
                    }
                }
            } else {
                /// Return a fallback color for iOS 12 and lower.
                return .red
            }
        }()
    }
}
```

after that in your viewController add the below code in the viewWillAppear method

```
yourView.backgroundColor = Mode.Colors.backgroundColor
```

Answer (score -1):

Add this in AppDelegate

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowColor = UITraitCollection.current.userInterfaceStyle == .light ? UIColor(named: "light_color") : UIColor(named: "dark_color")
```

Comment: we are already using this code but it is not working next time when we changed light mode to dark or dark to mode.

Comment: in asset add two color for any and dark and just assign that color name it will detect change in mode and automatic reflect your dark or light color as per selected mode

Answer (score -1):

#### remove navigationBar shadow

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
```

#### if iOS 13

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance.shadowColor = UIColor.black
```

Comment: Actually we are already added shadow but next time we will change mode then it will not reflect.

Answer (score -1):

```
override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
      super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)
      self.navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor 
  }
```

we are using this and it is working but we want only one class  we have to add this type of code like AppDelegate or some other classes .